# Multiply the results of a filter function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I'm sure the answer is extremely easy but I'm really new and couldn't find the answer online. I'm running a filter function and I am trying to multiply the results of the cells by another cell in the same columns filtered.

My filter function is :

```
=FILTER(C7:C127 ; D7:D127 > 0 ; ISNUMBER(D7:D127))
```

and I was all the results that show up to be multiplied by the value in the D columns of the same row. I tried this :

```
=FILTER(C7:C127 ; D7:D127 > 0 ; ISNUMBER(D7:D127))*FILTER(D7:D127 ; D7:D127 > 0 ; ISNUMBER(D7:D127))
```

but this only shows me the product of the first row that works with the filter but I would like all of them to show

Is there something I can change to make it work ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you share a public spreadsheet to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can actually multiply them "before" you apply the filter and it'll be a lot tidier.

```
=FILTER(C7:C127*D7:D127;N(D7:D127)>0)
```

the N() function just returns 0 for any text.  this allows you to get rid of the ISNUMBER() condition as it becomes moot.

Comment: Hey thanks ! I actually figured out you could multiply before, but the N() function is neat !

Answer (score 1):

Put more `ARRAYFORMULA()` to return as array

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(C7:C127 , D7:D127 > 0 , ISNUMBER(D7:D127))*FILTER(D7:D127 , D7:D127 > 0 , ISNUMBER(D7:D127)))
```